# Objective C - 2 simple questions

Tags: objective-c, class

1. What is the difference between using
   `@class` & `#import`? I had a situation
   where i was getting a build error,
   and the solution was to use `@class`
   instead of `#import` to import my
   class.
2. What does nonatomic mean? When do i
   use nonatomic to define a property,
   and when do i avoid it?

Comment: I think it's generally best practice to have separate questions. As for the second question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic

Comment: i believe it is #import you are saying instead of #define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@class` allows you to create a stub for a class that you will later define. For example:

**MyOtherClass.h**

```
@class MyClass;

@interface MyOtherClass : NSObject {
    MyClass *myObject;
}
```

**MyOtherClass.m**

```
#include "MyOtherClass.h"

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    NSUInteger myInt;
}
```

`#define` is used to define strings that will be replaced by the preprocessor. For example:

```
#define MY_INT 5

x = MY_INT;
```

will be rewritten by the pre-processor as:

```
x = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott G has already answered your question literally, but if, as Adam Ko said, you have meant #import, the answer would be that @class does not import the class but just tells the compiler that sometime later a class with the given name will be provided (in what is called "deferred binding" as I remember).

The @class is used mainly when you have two classes referring to each other, so they can not both import each other (that is probably the source of your compiler errors).

However, @class has a clear restriction that the compiler does not allow you to refer to any methods or attributes of the defined class. But usually you only need to use them in an implementation .m file, and there you can import the class without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

An atomic property is one for which the getter is guaranteed to return a valid, meaningful value even if the relevant setter is being called simultaneously on another thread. That costs more in processing terms than a nonatomic property, but is safer for multithreaded code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **atomic** (which is default) it does some magic to make your code perfectly thread-safe.

This magic costs something and that's why you see keyword **nonatomic** often, people use it if they don't really care about thread safety to make their code faster.